# Reactjs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.check = this.check.bind(this);
  }


 drawBackground() {
    console.log("worked");
}

  check () {
    this.myRef.current.innerHTML  = "Testing";
    {this.drawBackground()}      
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 ref={this.myRef} id="foo">bar</h1>
          {this.check()}
</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to access the `text` inside `h1` tag in the `check` function, but I get this error Reactjs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. I followed the documentation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ref is first set after the first render()

check the demo once [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6zqhsc)

You're referring the ref immediately after it is declared, Since the ref object receives the mounted instance of the component as its current.

If you're trying to access the DOM at the same time it's trying to generate it. this.myRef will not return anything because the component has no real DOM representation in render.

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign the value to the ref.
You are passing ref as a function.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.check = this.check.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    dom: null
  };

  drawBackground() {
    console.log("worked");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.check();
  }

  check() {
    const innerHTML = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.myRef).innerHTML;
    setTimeout(
      () => (ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.myRef).innerHTML = "TEST"),
      1000
    );
    console.log(innerHTML);
    this.setState({
      dom: innerHTML
    });
    {
      this.drawBackground();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 ref={ref => (this.myRef = ref)} id="foo">
          bar
        </h1>{" "}
        //You need to assign the value of the ref to the instance variable
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me create a codesandbox example to explain this

Comment: why are you executing `this.check()` inside render?

Comment: glad to help :)