# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined for this.refs.variable.value

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.

I have a input text like so

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number Only"
                                      value={that.state.value}
                                      ref={"qtype3" + item.questionId}
                                    />
```

now in a method I want to get the value inputted in the textbox,so i wrote following block in the method:

```
const uniqueNames = Array.from(new Set(this.state.arrrefs));

    if (uniqueNames.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < uniqueNames.length; i++) {
        var inval = uniqueNames[i];
        var ans = this.refs.inval.value;
        var newans = {
          taskId: this.props.location.state.tskId,
          userId: this.props.location.state.userid,
          questionId: "",
          answer: ans
        };
        this.state.radioObj.push(newans);
      }
    }
```

here arrrefs is an array in the state with refs of several textboxes. In the variable `inval` I am getting the first value of the arrrefs. but i am getting the exception in the line `var ans = this.refs.inval.value;`

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

If I pass a hardcode value in line `this.refs.inval.value` instead of `inval` I am getting response.

for example, my uniqueNames = ["qtype3800316", "qtype3800317", "qtype3800318", "qtype3800324"]

so i want this.refs.qtype3800316.value

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `uniqueNames` is the array containing ref.check updated question

Comment: are you sure that this.refs prints all the available refs ? and check this demo once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hg78fj !also  refs are accessible after first render and check this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955840/4061006

Comment: @Jayavel i checked your stackblitz. now suppose i have a submit button and i want to get the input data in each input field in submit button,how to do that..i want to check the user input and pass it to an api call.

Comment: @Jayavel i printed my uniqueNames in the console and got : `uniqueName :  (4) ["qtype3800316", "qtype3800317", "qtype3800318", "qtype3800324"]` .  and in . my `submit` method I did this : `uniqueNames.map(ele => 
      console.log(this[ele].value))}` but getting error `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` :(

Comment: Paste your codes in stackblitz that would be helpful ,

Comment: @Jayavel I used `document.getElementById(element).value` instead and its working now.thanks for taking time and helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `[]` operators if you want to access within an array/object by a variable.

`this.refs[inval].value`

Comment: No..`uniqueNames` is my array . and `inval` is an element of uniqueName array.like for eg. uniqueNames is  [name1,name2,name3,name4].  So in first iteration i will get inval as name1. and i am trying to get this.refs.name1.value

Answer (score 0):

Try just with: **this.refs.inval**

Also you can console.log(this.refs) and check what you have there.

Comment: its returning undefined

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230020/this-refs-something-returns-undefined